# IPv6 to ipv4 module for omnet++

Tags: ipv6, nat, ipv4

I'm using omnet++ for the simulation of two networks. One uses IPv6, the other one ipv4. Do you guys know if there is any IPv6 to IPv4 NAT module already available for omnet++? So far I haven't been able to find any, and writing one from scratch is not an easy task.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing yet.